# Yii urlManager check for missing string

Tags: regex, yii, routes, url-routing

I am working with the URL manager and all urls seem to be routing fine in yii. There is one thing though. I would like to insert a country name in the url if it is missing from a set of countries.

```
'/' to '/uae'
'/ar' to 'ar/uae'
'/ar/bla/bla' to 'ar/uae/bla/bla'
```

In all cases 'uae' or 'bahrain' or 'qatar' should be present.

Write now my urls are setup as follows:

```
    '<lang:ar>/<country:uae | bahrain>/'=>'categories', //DONE
    '<lang:ar>/<country:uae | bahrain>/<make:\w+>'=>'categories/view', //DONE
    '<lang:ar>/<country:uae | bahrain>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>'=>'subcategories/view/',
    '<lang:ar>/<country:uae | bahrain>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>/<year:\w+>'=>'items/view/',

    '<lang:ar>/'=>'categories', //DONE
    '<lang:ar>/<make:\w+>'=>'categories/view', //DONE
    '<lang:ar>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>'=>'subcategories/view/',
    '<lang:ar>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>/<year:\w+>'=>'items/view/',

    '<country:uae | bahrain>/'=>'categories', //DONE
    '<country:uae | bahrain>>/<make:\w+>'=>'categories/view', //DONE
    '<country:uae | bahrain>>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>'=>'subcategories/view/',
    '<country:uae | bahrain>>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>/<year:\w+>'=>'items/view/',


    '/'=>'categories', //DONE
    '<make:\w+>'=>'categories/view', //DONE
    '<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>'=>'subcategories/view/',
    '<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>/<year:\w+>'=>'items/view/',
```

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to explain better what result you're trying to achieve.

It is also important to know if this should affect all of your urls or just some, because generally when working with language and country it should be a general approach that affects the entire website.

So I can see you've got two parameters, language and country, are they going to be there always?

Are you going to always prefix the urls of your application with those parameters? or do you want to have urls also without language and country that internally will take some default values?

For example, at HeavyDots we have english language urls, without any prefix, and the rest of the languages, Spanish and Romanian, are prefixed with their own folder `es` and `ro`:

```
http://heavydots.com/about/
http://heavydots.com/es/about/
http://heavydots.com/ro/about/
```

So if you are always going to prefix with language and country I suggest you only keep one list of routes, for example:

```
'<lang:(lang1|lang2|lang3)>/<country:(country1|country2|country3)>/'=>'categories', //DONE
'<lang:(lang1|lang2|lang3)>/<country:(country1|country2|country3)>/<make:\w+>'=>'categories/view', //DONE
'<lang:(lang1|lang2|lang3)>/<country:(country1|country2|country3)>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>'=>'subcategories/view/',
'<lang:(lang1|lang2|lang3)>/<country:(country1|country2|country3)>/<make:\w+>/<model:\w+>/<year:\w+>'=>'items/view/',
```

As for when a user visits the site for the first time, you could either redirect from the default `SiteController::index` action if no language and country was found in the url, and redirect it to `categories` with default lang and country params.

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang']) || !isset($_GET['country'])) {
    $this->redirect(array('categories','lang'=>'lang1','country'=>'country1'));
}
```

Or you could keep the rule of the root url to `categories`:

```
'/'=>'categories',
```

And simply set some default values to lang and country internal variables if nothing is available in `$_GET`.

A few more tips..

1) How are you applying language? Are you doing it at application-level or manually on every controller?

A fast way to do it is by using `components/Controller.php`, example:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
      Yii::app()->language=$_GET['lang'];
    }
}
```

2) A faster way to prefix all your routes with language support and have a more dynamic result, and cleaner rules definition, can be to extend the `CUrlManager`, and inside its `init` method, loop all the rules and modify/multiply them massively

3) A cleaner/faster way to generate urls without having to always pass the lang parameter in every url creation command, would be to extend the `CUrlManager` and modify its `createUrl` method, and if no `lang` parameter is found when creating the url, it defines this parameter with the value of the active language. So you only pass `lang` parameter when you need to change language, but for the rest of the url creation you skip it and it will be added automatically.

If you need more examples on any of the tips let me know. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alexandru. Thanks for your reply. I am applying them at an application level and yes it should affect the whole website. We only have 1 language which is 'ar' for arabic. If the language is not present in the url i.e 'ar' then the default language is english which does not need to be in the url. The urls can be "ar/country/bla/bla/bla" or "country/bla/bla/bla". But the country should be present. If not present it should be automactially added. e.g. "ar/bla/bla" should become "ar/uae/bla/bla" - uae here is the default country. "bla/bla/bla" should become "uae/bla/bla/bla" - uae is default

Comment: I would prefer if it can be dont on the .htaccess level, if not then UrlManager is fine. I have put my rules in the main.php file in yii config folder.